# how to use struts bean tags in my Custom tags?

Tags: java, jsp, struts1

I have one custom button tag to handle my functionality, I want some values from the struts bean tags to fulfill my functionality. I am nesting struts tags inside my custom tag. 
 

My code in JSP looks like below.

```
<button:button  module="MyModule" subModule="MySubModule" aliasType="ButtonType" aliasName="SaveButtonGroup" 
   onClick="addNewPart('<bean:Write property="paymentNumber" name="payment" />','<bean:Write property="transactionId" name="payment" />') </button:button>
```

But, I am getting the below error while running

```
weblogic.servlet.jsp.CompilationException: Failed to compile JSP /JSP/cdr/tdsDetails.jsp
tdsDetails.jsp:1:1: The page failed validation from validator: "org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Attribute "name" was already specified for element "button:button".".
tdsDetails.jsp:308:59: This attribute is not recognized.
onClick="addNewPart('<bean:Write    property="paymentNumber" name="payment" />','<bean:Write    property="transactionId" name="payment" />');"></button:button>
```

what would be the solution? Thanks in Advance for your help.

Comment: The double quotes (") before addNewPart is not closed properly at the end. Try removing it or closing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simplify by ditching the Stuts tags and just using EL:

```
<button:button  module="MyModule" subModule="MySubModule" aliasType="ButtonType" aliasName="SaveButtonGroup" 
   onClick="addNewPart('${payment.paymentNumber}','${payment.transactionId}')"> </button:button>
```

Comment: Thanks @Alan for your time. It works for me.  but what is the reason behind the error? can't we nested struts tags in our custom tags?

Comment: @Gopal Of course not; you can't nest *any* JSP tags. Think of JSP like XML in this regard; you can't put an XML element anywhere other than as a sibling or child of another.